# Is there a best way to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Can some one please help in joining/merging the table like below.

I know how to do if the department columns (depart_1, depart_2, depart_3) are in one table. but not able to achieve this scenario as they are in different tables.

I have almost 100 fields like department, so little concern about performance as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `JOIN` and `UNION`

```sql
SELECT
  id, name gender, 1 as seq, depart_1 as department
FROM tab 1
UNION 
SELECT
  id, name gender, 2 as seq, depart_2 as department
FROM tab 1
UNION
SELECt
  tab1.id, tab2.name, tab1.gender, 3 as seq, tab2.depart_3 as department
FROM tab2 JOIN tab1 on tab2.id = tab1.id
UNION
SELECt
  tab1.id, tab2.name, tab1.gender, 4 as seq, tab2.depart_4 as department
FROM tab2 JOIN tab1 on tab2.id = tab1.id
UNION
SELECT
   tab1.id, tab3.name, tab1.gender, 5 as seq, tab3.depart_5 as department
FROM tab3 JOIN tab1 on tab3.id = tab1.id
UNION
SELECT
   tab1.id, tab3.name, tab1.gender, 6 as seq, tab3.depart_6 as department
FROM tab3 JOIN tab1 on tab3.id = tab1.id
```

Each query reads one department info. So you can us static number in each query for seq column.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I have update the tables with the requirement. hope this will answer your question on seq. Seq number is something like the number of department fields for ex: 1-6 in this example

Comment: When I query first and second select statements, I'm able to get all the records individually. but when I add union then I am getting only first record from the tables. I mean first three records in the expected result. id(102) is not at all displaying.

Comment: Hmm... `UNION`removes duplicates. Try `UNION ALL` instead. But your sample data doesn't have duplicate results.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do all the unions first and then perform the smaller join at the end .

```
SELECT tab.id,
    tab.name,
    gen.gender,
    tab.seq,
    tab.deparment
FROM
    (SELECT id, name, 1 as seq, depart_1 as department FROM tab 1
    UNION 
    SELECT id, name , 2 as seq, depart_2 as department FROM tab 1
    UNION
    SELECT id, name, 3 as seq, depart_3 as department FROM tab 2
    UNION 
    SELECT id, name , 4 as seq, depart_4 as department FROM tab 2) tab LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id,gender FROM tab1 ) gen ON tab.id=gen.id
```

Since you are doing it in hive , This will automatically perform map-side join which will make your query much faster.